# RandomGenerator - Losing 50% of planes simulation

Tags: java

I'm working on a problem that I'm a little confused on. The question says imagine you're a general of the British Air Force during WW2. You have 100 planes left to defend the United Kingdom. With each mission you fly each plane has a 50% chance of getting shot down by the German anti aircraft guns so every mission you'll lose about half of your planes. You have to write a program that will approximate how many planes will survive after each mission and how many missions you can run until all your planes get shot down.

My program does not work and I don't know what wrong with it so I guess England is in trouble. I'm trying to solve this problem with two while loops. The outer while loop says as long as you have planes left send them on another mission. The inner while loop simulates the actual mission. After the while loop exists the total number of planes is now the surviving planes.

```
import acm.program.*; 
import acm.util.*;

public class MissionPlanes extends ConsoleProgram{
public void run(){

  int planes = 100;  /* total number of planes */
  int suvPlanes = 0;  /* surviving planes  */
  int mission = 0;      /* total number of missions */
  int planeCounter = 0;   /* keeps track of the planes flying over the anti plane gun  */


  while (planes > 0){

       while(planeCounter < planes){
             planeCounter++;
             if(rgen.nextBoolean()){   /* I've tried rgen.nextBoolean() with paramaters and with no paramaters */
              suvPlanes += 1;
                   }
            }
    planes = suvPlanes;
    mission++;
 println("The total number of surviving planes you have is " + planes + "after" + missoin + "missions"); 
     }
  }
  private RandomGenerator rgen = RandomGenerator.getInstance();
      }
```

Comment: Please elaborate on 'it does not work'. In what way does it not work?

Comment: Does `nextBoolean` take any parameters?

Comment: @Patashu nothing happens. It does not print anything on the screen. I believe I've done everything correct.

Comment: _Abstraction!_ If the inner loop counts the suvPlanes (survivingPlanes), should not it start with 0, just before its loop?

Comment: @Blender yes sorry I left that out the first time. I've corrected it

Comment: @JessicaM. Nothing? And you're sure that you look at the console? And that you actually call this `run()` method somewhere?

Comment: @PiotrChojnacki yes I've double checked everything. I'm a little stumped.

Comment: @JessicaM. Ok, well, seems like England really is in trouble then.

But just to be sure, can you show us code where you call this `run()` method?

Comment: @PiotrChojnacki public void run(){....} at the top of the page.

Comment: @JessicaM. That's where it's declared. What code will call `run()` when your program starts execution in `main()`?

Comment: @Patashu I honestly don't know to be honest with you. I push the run button in eclipse and it runs it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will have to reset `planeCounter` to 0 in the outer cycle. Same holds for `suvPlanes`:

```
while (planes > 0){
  planeCounter = 0;
  suvPlanes = 0;
  // ... remaining stuff
```

If you don't do that on the second iteration of this cycle you will end up with `planeCounter >= planes` so you will not execute the inner cycle. On the other hand `suvPlanes` will not be reset to 0 so planes will forever remain equal to the value of `suvPlanes` in the first cycle and thus your outer cycle will never terminate.

Comment: trying out your suggestion right now and seeing if I can get it to work.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion. It works and says "total number of surviving planes you have is 0 after 6 missions" I'm trying to print how many planes after the 1st mission then after the 2nd, then 3rd until I have no planes left.

Comment: It works...it finally works!!!! Thanks so much for your help. So you have to reset the planeCounter and suvPlanes before the start of every loop because they'll still have the value from the previous loop. Is that right?

Comment: Jessica, a possible solution is to use a for(int planeCounter = 0; planeCounter = < planes; planeCounter++) instead of that second while. That way you don't need to reset the value each time.

Comment: @simonVerhoeven that's really interesting. I've never thought about it like that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You should reset both planeCounter and survivingPlanes.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I didn't realize that if you don't reset the counter for planeCounter and survivingPlanes they'll both have the values from the previous loop.

Answer (score 2):

Your class does not have a main method (I am assuming you are running this on it's own).  Also there are some logical errors in the code, as well as some import statements, that my compiler at least is not happy with.

I've cleaned it up and added a main method:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class MissionPlanes {


    public static void main(String[] args){
        Random rgen = new Random();

        int planes = 100;  /* total number of planes */
        int suvPlanes = 0;  /* surviving planes  */
        int mission = 0;      /* total number of missions */
        int planeCounter = 0;   /* keeps track of the planes flying over the anti plane gun  */


        while (planes > 0){

            while(planeCounter < planes){
                planeCounter++;
                if(rgen.nextBoolean()){   /* I've tried rgen.nextBoolean() with paramaters and with no paramaters */
                suvPlanes ++;
                }
            }
            planes = suvPlanes;
            suvPlanes = 0;
            planeCounter = 0;
            mission++;
            System.out.println("The total number of surviving planes you have is " 
            + planes + " after " + mission + " missions"); 
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I appreciate your input.

Answer (score 1):

Your program does not compile.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextBoolean() says that nextBoolean() takes no parameters, yet you are giving it one. Probably your program is not compiling and you are running an older version of it.

Comment: I've tried both with parameters of .5 and with no parameters. Still does not work. I don't know where I went wrong.

Comment: @JessicaM. You need to read the compiler errors for your program and resolve them all.

Answer (score 1):

I re modified your code and you can run this `

```
static Random mRandom = new Random();
static int totalPlanes = 100;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    run();
}

public static void run() {
    int planes = totalPlanes; /* total number of planes */
    int suvPlanes = 0; /* surviving planes */
    int mission = 0; /* total number of missions */
    int planeCounter = 0; /*
                         * keeps track of the planes flying over the anti
                         * plane gun
                         */

    // it is default that it would encounter the anti plane gun if its in a
    // mission so don't use planeCounter
    // and this method assume that the general is sending one plane at a
    // time
    while (planes > 0) {
        if (mRandom.nextBoolean()) {// 50% chance it can survive
            suvPlanes += 1;
        } else {
            // decrease the plane count when is not survived
            planes -= 1;
        }
        mission++;
        System.out
                .println("The total number of survived planes you have is "
                        + suvPlanes + " after " + mission
                        + " missions and " + "the original no of plane "
                        + planes);
    }
}
```

` Just run to get the answer